# Incorporating impulse responses while forecasting macro variables

Tags: time-series, forecasting, econometrics, macroeconomics, impulse-response

I am forecasting a few macro variables such as inflation rate (INF), GDP, unemployment rate (UNRATE), federal funds rate (FFR) etc. Then, I imposed a 2 % upward shock on the federal funds rate, and the examined the impact of the shock on other variables by creating impulse response functions and plotting them. Suppose the horizon is 20. So, I have 20 observations

For example: INF_FFR: (20 x 1) vector that stores the impulse response of INF when FFR rises by 2 %

Now, I want to forecast INF taking into account the shock on FFR (scenario analysis). So, my plot will have the historical values of INF plus the forecasts.

In order to create the forecasts, I estimated a simple ARIMA model for INF, found the forecasts without the shock (FCST) and the 90 percent forecast interval. How I do I incorporate INF_FFR? Should I just add them to the forecasts? i.e. FCST + INF_FFR?

Comment: Just commenting here, in the hopes that someone might see and respond. I really appreciate your help.